# What is the relationship between Enum and Enumeration, if any

Tags: java

I wonder what is a formal connection if any between [Enumeration interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) in Java and an [Enum construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is none, they're for entirely different things. [`enums`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) are for enumerated constants. [`Enumeration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) is a largely-outdated interface superceded by [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: That's what i suspected. Thanks